# Where and how to configure django-cms's djangocms_text_ckeditor to strip <p> tags?

Tags: django, content-management-system, ckeditor, django-cms, rich-text-editor

I can't find the djangocms_text_ckeditor app anywhere in my django virtualenv directorys. I didn't found a clue in the django-cms documentation in how to configure the editor.

I don't want the ckeditor always wraps `<p>`-tags around a simple text string (like a telephone number).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can answer this question myself:
To configure the editor you use the settings.py and just add this:

```
    CKEDITOR_SETTINGS = {
    'autoParagraph': False
}
```

This configuration inserts valid javascript configuration in the ckeditor javascript files.